# java.io.* freezes netbeans in JSP

Tags: jsp, netbeans, java-io

Whenever I am making a JSP page in netbeans, I try to import java.IO.*

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
```

, it freezes the IDE. I am using windows 7x64 Pro. This happens in NetBeans 7.2.1 and 7.3. Is it against the rules to use that particular import? It seems strange that a bug like this would be present in both of the latest versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be some other issue. It works fine for me on NetBeans 7.3 Windows 7x64 Pro.

On a side note, Its not good practice to import complete package.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine when I just import each individual item as needed, so I'll do that instead.